# Resizing svg without croping the image

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I converted svg into React Component using
https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/

When I placed it in an app component it crops the image. What is the proper way to resize/scale svg inside a component without affecting the image.

```
You can find the svg code here https://pastebin.com/KbwYDCDP
```

Comment: Try removing the width and height of the svg element. Since there is a viewBox attribute the svg element should take the parent's width.

Comment: Tried removing height and width, the image then just disappers. You can check svg code here https://pastebin.com/KbwYDCDP